# Add a minute to a string

Tags: python

Is there an easy way to add a minute to a TIMESTAMP string? For example:

```
t1 = '02:20:03'
t1 + 1min = '02:21:03'
```

The current way I'm doing it is

```
(datetime.combine(date.today(), self.video_length) - timedelta(minutes=2)).time()
```

But that seems a bit cumbersome. Is there a simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the dateutil library can parse most things you throw at it magically

(you may have to  `pip install python-dateutil`)

```
import dateutil.parser as p

(p.parse("02:20:03")+datetime.timedelta(minutes=2)).time()
```

maybe?

a better idea would be to probably store it as a datetime and only print it to a string when you need to (but I dont have enough context to know if that is viable or not)

Comment: When I try doing this I get the following error: `>>> p.parse("02:20:03")+datetime.timedelta(minutes=2).time()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'time'`

Comment: was missing a parenthesis